# "Failed unmounting /cdrom", stuck on "systemmd-rfkill.service"

Tags: boot, system-installation, mount, kubuntu, lubuntu

I am unable to install both Lubuntu and Kubuntu 20.04 as of recent on my laptop. I am utilizing a USB, however, it appears to be giving a CDROM error message, one of which I do not have. If it is of any help, I have an option to boot from CDROM, despite not actually seeing any place to put a CD in on my laptop. I have verified both .iso file checksums and used both Rufus and balenaEtcher.

Lubuntu Error Message:

[image: Screen photo 1]

Kubuntu Error Message:

[image: Screen photo 2]

Comment: The CDROM is how your installation media is referenced; ie. errors relating to CDROM refer to your installation media be it on hdd/ssd/thumb-drive/flash/CF-card/etc (inc CD/DVD should someone still use them). The usual cause is a bad write, or outdated software used to do the write (that can't handle the ISO file being used). I do see a "*Check Finished: no errors found*" on one that makes it look like validation passed, but the other looks invalid (ie. invalid ISO but you said it was validated; so likely bad write to thumb-drive).  (*picture is hard to read so I could have missed things*)

Comment: Interesting, are there any proper instructions utilizing Rufus to write to USB, specifically for Kubuntu? Sorry for the bad quality by the way, I was going to try to run an OCR on it so I could copy paste the text but the internet's pretty spotty here.

Comment: All Ubuntu ISOs for the same release are identical (ie. Kubuntu 21.10 is the same as Ubuntu 21.10, Kubuntu 20.04 the same as Ubuntu 20.04), but over time the ISOs change thus software like `rufus` needs to be updated. You can search for material using `rufus site:*.ubuntu.com`  which will get results like https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick/fromWindows & more (it's what showed up first for me using startpage.com; being last edited 2021-07-25 so I'd expect accurate), the second a discourse/review page for what appears at tutorial.ubuntu.com etc.

Comment: Be aware that when using Rufus you must select the proper options before "burning" the ISO. Most often you want UEFI/GPT for any modern PC, 10 years old (at least) or newer and BIOS/MBR for legacy hardware.